# how to Create a Transactionscope between saving a file and inserting a record in DB in C#

Tags: c#, file-io, transactions, insert, dependencies

I have a problem, for saving a file and inserting a record in DB in a TransactionScope; Means saving file and inserting record, must depend together = or both or neither. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: post some of your code, what exactly is your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try
{
    // Start DB Transaction
    // Save To DAtabase code
    // Save To File Code
    // Commit DB Transaction
}
catch
{
    // Rollback DB Transaction
}
```

Please notice Sequence of DB should be first then Saving to the file.

Answer (score 7):

Transactional NTFS

> One of the coolest parts about
>   Transactional NTFS is that it can work
>   with a large number of other
>   transactional technologies. Because
>   TxF uses the new Kernel Transaction
>   Manager (KTM) features, and because
>   the new KTM can work directly with the
>   Microsoft® Distributed Transaction
>   Coordinator (DTC), any technology that
>   can work with DTC as a transaction
>   coordinator can use transacted file
>   operations within a single
>   transaction. This means that you can
>   now enlist transacted file operations
>   within the same transaction as **SQL**
>   operations, Web service calls via
>   WS-AtomicTransaction, Windows
>   Communication Foundation services via
>   the OleTransactionProtocol, or even
>   transacted MSMQ operations.

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163388.aspx)

[Alpha FS](http://alphafs.codeplex.com/) provides Transaction NTFS in .NET.
see Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.KernelTransaction(Transaction transaction). You can get the current transaction by Transaction.Current

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew))
{
    //KernelTransaction is in AlphaFS
    KernelTransaction kt = new KernelTransaction(Transaction.Current);

    //Append "hello" to text file named "text.txt"
    Alphaleonis.Win32.Filesystem.File.WriteAllText(kt, "text.txt", "hello");

    //No text appended because exception will be thrown
    throw new Exception("oops");

    ts.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks dear pebrian27; In this project I'm on it, this is not necessary for me; but in another project, I'm going on it soon as soon, your help and code-sample is very very useful for me, thanks a lot, best regards.