# How to use TransactionScope to wrap a file copy & call to web service?

Tags: c#, wpf, transactions, transactionscope

I'd like to utilize a TransactionScope in this situation and while I think it's the right approach, I've never done it and am running into difficulty.

In pseudo-code, what I'd like to do is the following:

- begin transaction

  - copy file to destination (windows desktop client to netapp share)
  - call a web service which will in turn add a reference to that file in the database
- if a file copy error occurs or the web service doesn't respond successfully, roll back

  - delete the file from the remote location if it still exists
  - call a web service to delete the reference to the file, which will delete it if it exists
- complete transaction

Do I need to define my own resource managers for the file copy and web service operations so that they can properly implement rollback?

I've been attempting to search around but if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I preferred the Try-Catch method myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535134/how-to-create-a-transactionscope-between-saving-a-file-and-inserting-a-record-in

Answer (score 0):

While I am far from an expert with using `TransactionScope` objects, I do *not* believe that you can rollback non database functionality with them. However, it *is* possible to add non related functionality into them without problem. As @JeremyThompson has correctly mentioned, you would need to add a `try`and `catch` block to make this work:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    try
    {
        // Do your database work here

        // Then do your hard drive work here

        transactionScope.Complete();
    }
    catch
    {
        // Manually rollback your hard drive work here
    }
}
```