# Transactional Write of multiple FileStreams in C#

Tags: c#, file, file-io, transactions, transactional

I'm supposed to get multiple files with the same extension (for example, an archive that's split into several archives: rar, r00, r01, etc).

I'm trying to find a solution where if one of the file streams I got fails to be written, all the previously successful files that were created will be deleted.
Just like a transactional file stream writer.

I've bumped into [.NET Transactional File Manager](https://transactionalfilemgr.codeplex.com/) project, which seems just like what I need -- except it doesn't work with streams but with file paths.

At this point I only see two options:

- Keeping a list of successful file writes and if other one will fail, I'll go over the list and delete all.
- Write all files to %TEMP% or something via FileStream and then - after all files were written successfully, I'll use the Transactional File Manager (mentioned above) to move the files to the desired location.

Need to notice that I have to work with streams

Which of the two options is better in your opinion?
Is there any better recommendation or idea for doing this?

Thanks

*Edit*:

Another option I bumped into is using [AlphaFS](http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com/) just like in the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535395/2419751).
Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Did you went through the source code of the transactional file manager? It actually copies the original files to the %TEMP% first, using File.Copy, then operates on the original files (AppendAllText, WriteAllBytes, etc..). When you call RollBack, it just copies the file at the %TEMP% back to it's original location. Just like you planned in option 2.

Comment: Be aware  - _[This library is NOT a wrapper of Transactional NTFS. It simply implements IEnlistmentNotification and allow manual standard file operations to work with TransactionScope. For instance, to enable rollback for a write operation on an existing file, it first creates a backup of the file that will be written, then writes to the backuped file, and finally replaces the initial file with the backuped/modified file if the transaction is committed, or deletes the backup file if the transaction is rollbacked. This has nothing to do with Transactional NTFS](http://tinyurl.com/os23uyy)_

Comment: I think the best option would be to create a directory with a unique name (timestamp + newguid would do) under the %TEMP%, and then writing all your files under that directory. If all file operations succeed, (and streams are disposed, closed) move the directory to it's final location. If any of the files fail, (and streams are disposed, closed), delete the directory with Directory.Delete

Comment: Please _try_ something. Your question is "too broad" or "primarily opinion-based", depending on how much detail you're looking for in an answer. You'll learn a lot about whether either option you see will work for you, and if so which one seems best _for your scenario_. If in the process of working on this, you run into a _specific_ problem, please feel free to post a question with [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces that problem, with a precise explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using AlphaFS.
Using it just like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6535395/2419751) example.
It works perfectly and does exactly what I was needed.

Thanks for all the comments.